# Android messaging application, aware of ages or numbers

Tags: android, chat, android-app

Are there any messaging applications which allow assigning age/number for each message?

It would be attached in the message, for example on the left for left to right system, and assign the numbers and send them after I have written the various messages.

Comment: Can you please explain what problem you're are trying to solve with that?